# Meaning of 'Way to [something]'

Tags: meaning, irony

I was wondering if "way to do something" means it is right or wrong to do something.

I thought it meant that something was done right, until I read this:

> Just a few doors down, Lynette's sister shows up just in time to help her through her split with Tom. Unfortunately the once messy sibling shows up looking fabulous and on the arm of a sexy new boyfriend. **Way to make Lynette feel good about herself!!!** Don't you hate when that happens? When a friend or loved one shows up to try to help you through a troubling time and all they do is flaunt all of the fabulous things that are going on in their life.

Comment: "a sarcasm detector? Oh, that's a real useful invention"

Comment: @Sam: What did you mean?

Comment: Sorry, it's a quote from the Simpsons. The sentence in question is clearly sarcastic.  I would think most use of 'way to' these days is used in this ironic way. They clearly don't mean the sentence literally.

Answer (score 9):

*Way to X* **usually** is an exclamation of approval, encouragement, a positive reaction. However, in the example you posted it's meant ironically, so it's the exact opposite.

Some references you might be interested in:

[way to go!](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/way_to_go):

> (idiomatic) an expression of congratulations, encouragement, or approval

This is a very close phrase to what you got there above. Similar example would be: "Way to score, man!"

However, beware of another phrase, [what a way to go!](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what_a_way_to_go):

> (set phrase) expression or remark on the unfortunate, exceptional, or unusual nature of somebody's death

This one is similar to saying for example, "what a waste!" or "what a strange idea!"

Comment: "Way to X" is used primarily sarcastically in all contexts post-kindergarten, in my experience.

Comment: "Way to go!" can still be an expression of approval.

Comment: Only the context will tell you if the phrase is positive or negative. The example is explained as being negative

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if "way to do something" means it is right or wrong to do something?

It means "That's the way to do it!" and it can be positive or negative - encouraging or ironic.

Only the context will tell you if the phrase is positive or negative.