# Are both of these Raising’s?

Tags: infinitives, subjects

> [i] **Equi**
>   Billᵢ wants [[(for) Billᵢ] to leave at noon]
>   [Billᵢ wants [ __ ᵢ to leave at noon]]
>   [ii] **Raising**
>   [[(For) the casserole] to be done] seems
>   The casserole seems [to be done]
>   (Prof.John Lawler's [article](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf))

[case 1] She was last to arrive.([OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/last_1))
[i] Equi: She was last [[for her] to arrive].
[ii] Raising: [[For her] to arrive] was last.

[case 2] They were the last to arrive.([OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/last_3))
[i] Equi: They were the last [[for them] to arrive]].
[ii] Raising: [[For them] to arrive] was the last.

Are both, case 1 and case 2, Raising’s? 
I tilt my head once one way, then the other. May I get the idea clear?

Comment: Cases 1 and 2 have already been done things to. Put back all the stuff that was taken out before you worry about Equi and Raising. I'll answer presently, but this is a chance to figure out the logic and what other concepts are involved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really not about Raising or Equi; let's look at at the sentences:

1. *She was last to arrive.*
2. *They were the last to arrive.*

There are a couple of irrelevant differences between them.

- Sentence (2) uses ***the** last*, while (1) uses no article (both versions are grammatical here)
- Sentence (1) has a singular subject and verb, while (2) has plurals.
  Aside from these differences, however, the sentences are the same in structure.
  I'll concentrate on (1) here.

(1) has a lot of deletions -- i.e, lots of words are missing.
(This is grammatical; it's all done by rules)
(1) is equivalent to

- *She was **the** last to arrive.*
- *She was the last **one** to arrive.*
- *She was the last **person** to arrive.*
- *She was the last one **who arrived**.*
- *She was the last one **of the people** who arrived.*

The infinitive *to arrive* in (1) and (2) is a [***Relative Infinitive***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/60903/15299), not a Complement Infinitive.
Since it's not a subject or object complement clause of *last*, Raising is not applicable.
More on relative infinitives [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/54858/15299).

In this case the predicate is a definite noun phrase containing a relative infinitive

- [`vp` (***was***) [`np` (*the*) ***last*** (*one*) (*of the people*) ***to arrive*** `np`] `vp`]

and there is no complement clause.