# Use of "put something in" vs "in which to put something"

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, sentence-ends, is-it-a-rule

What is the rule or the error involving, for example;

> I need a box to put my groceries in.

vs

> I need a box in which to put my groceries.

Comment: Both forms work. What kind of 'rule' or 'error' are you trying to find?

Comment: This construction is called a [Relative Infinitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/60903/15299). It consists of an infinitive with _to_ following and modifying an antecedent noun, and also containing a reference to the antecedent. Like _box_ is the object of the preposition _in_, in both examples. Relative infinitives, unlike tensed relative clauses, don't use relative pronouns like _which_ or _who_ (_He's the man to speak with,_ but not *_He's the man who(m) to speak with_), **except** when there's a pied-piped preposition, like _in_ (or _to_ in _He's the man to whom to speak_).

Answer (score 0):

The only real difference is casual vs formal language (pure preference in 99% of situations).

> I need a box to put my groceries in.

is casual, as it ends in a preposition.

> I need a box in which to put my groceries.

is the more formal version of the same statement (not ending in a preposition).

See [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/youve-been-lied-to-heres-why-you-absolutely-can-end-a-sentence-with-a-preposition/) for more.

Comment: See https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/11/14/churchill-on-prepositions/